# Using persistent disks with google Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I use google cloud for a hpc project. I have multiple instances writing and reading from from the same persistent disk (mounted using sshfs). I want to analyze some data using Datalab, and I'm not sure how to mount the persistent disk from Datalab (which natively uses google storage). Should I just execute the mount as a bash command from within my notebook, or is there a more elegant way to set things up? Am I wrong sticking with persistent disks over google storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use a %%bash cell and do the mount that way if that is easiest. Sorry for the slow response.

There is no right or wrong answer for where to store your data; it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you develop this answer a bit? Running `!ls /mnt` and `!ls /media` both return empty content. How can I mount the persistent disk?

(The disk is visible by the Datalab VM if I check with a ssh session)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the disk is already attached to the instance, you can mount with bash by ssh'ing to the instance:

```
# find the name of the attached disk
lsblk

# set the name of the disk to <disk-name>
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/<disk-name>
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/<disk-name
```